# How is this Isapi Rewrite rule actually working?

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi

```
#add in the www
RewriteCond Host: (?:http\://)?drink-superstore\.com
RewriteRule (.+) http\://www.drink-superstore.com$1 [I,RP]
```

We have it in one of our sites and I need it in another but I did not want to just use it without understanding it.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteCond` is a condition, like an IF statement. It tests to see if the HOST is drink-superstore.com, with no leading www.  If the condition evaluates to true, then the rule is applied for the request.

The rule says: **Redirect** to the same url ($1), using a different host, with the www prefix.  The redirect comes in with the RP option, which stands for "Redirect Permanently".  That is an HTTP 301 response code.

Answer (score 0):

More information on ISAPI rewrite can be found [here](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/). I learned how to use URL rewrites from [this handy page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).Its part of the official Apache documentation.But also [here is a tutorial](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) for beginners on URL rewriting. While its geared towards apache, This should at least provide somewhere to start.